# How can I build a Google Maps URL for directions with waypoints that also works in mobile apps?

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, url, directions

I'm working on a web application that makes use of the [Google Maps Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro). I am trying to create a hyperlink below some dynamically created directions (using lat/lon coordinates as waypoints) that will allow a mobile user to view and interact with the same directions on their mobile device.

As an example, I have created a directions link with 3 waypoints made from lat/lon pairs. The first is to the Southwest of Atlanta *(33.67,-84.61)*. The second is to the North *(34.01,-84.33)*, and the third is to the Southeast *(33.66,-84.10)*. (Think of drawing a simple "A" shape over the city of Atlanta.) Using several aging 3rd party guides and other StackOverflow answers, I've made the simplest version of a maps URL that seems to return my desired result. It looks like this:

http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&saddr=33.67,-84.61&daddr=34.01,-84.33+to:33.66,-84.10

**This directions URL works fine in a web browser, even a mobile one, but seems to have differing results in both iOS and Android native versions of the Google Maps application.** Below are screenshots of some testing I was able to do on the above URL.

- [Android Google Maps app](https://photos-6.dropbox.com/t/2/AAAxjE4nNGVnJxcfi5ivQlx408EhlFOLuht_foa_4H5q0g/12/12349073/png/32x32/3/1447981200/0/2/Android_Marshmellow_Native.png/EJPNlgkY67oBIAIoAg/73zV8wuuP3Fz69enAF-9gyKgcJWB4Ynq5Xv2vaqAP9c?size_mode=2&size=1600x1200) - Gives directions from the start address (`saddr`) to the first waypoint and ignores anything else.
- [iOS 9 Google Maps app](https://photos-5.dropbox.com/t/2/AADV8iwcvMfzlg4YI7MZT5xH4gjL8S7Fi1ZvtPW6rD8jyQ/12/12349073/png/32x32/1/_/1/2/iOS_9_Native.png/EJPNlgkY67oBIAIoAg/ZTSieTElXaTlOGSpE1Nyh550Wzw8rcjgIulHRg3qJrk?size=1600x1200&size_mode=2) - Gives directions from the `saddr` to the last waypoint *and ignores points between!*

The very same URL seems to play nice when you open it with:

- [Android Marshmallow Chrome](https://photos-6.dropbox.com/t/2/AADZyBLZX8I0wrPp0F2EFjD1Ii9AmXcsiJCbiIV1O7gKXQ/12/12349073/png/32x32/1/_/1/2/Android_Marshmellow_Chrome.png/EJPNlgkY67oBIAIoAg/hYA872pvWEEmCYTmgj9Hk4tDUhcKySsoWD8hedNXXpc?size=1600x1200&size_mode=2)
- [iOS 9 Chrome](https://photos-1.dropbox.com/t/2/AACgkPD_rTlH33Jq7y223VUmDZ5t9qC1st1THP7AAwzLmw/12/12349073/png/32x32/1/_/1/2/iOS_9_Chrome.png/EJPNlgkY67oBIAIoAg/9uI8wXxAyjaHYEgv1JjUXzNow-fBM8WQn-VozQlfBUE?size=1600x1200&size_mode=2)
- [iOS 9 Safari](https://photos-2.dropbox.com/t/2/AACN_7xV1OVJHfiIpODMiDXkXsCq3pwo_ogh7KCagLW5BA/12/12349073/png/32x32/1/_/1/2/iOS_9_Safari.png/EJPNlgkY67oBIAIoAg/JmSJ58e3unM5HQnYIZ_fPt3ZRlfzTrgnWyxpasdmNGw?size=1600x1200&size_mode=2)
- [Windows 7 Chrome](https://photos-6.dropbox.com/t/2/AABxglqCNv_rBDw7gtLXZtK7fFF2puiGKdqsaFVi3Gtj3g/12/12349073/png/32x32/1/_/1/2/Windows_7_Chrome.png/EJPNlgkY67oBIAIoAg/6hyyVT3UIwPmJNr8yNAV0YNHFG3Al-MjHT9sEvbn9DM?size=1600x1200&size_mode=2)

Does Google officially document these URL routes somewhere? What parameters can I use to accomplish my goal of consistency for direction link behavior across mobile platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can request multiple stop directions to launch Google Maps like below,

**Forming the Directions URL**

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&parameters
```

**Usage:**

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=Paris%2CFrance&destination=Cherbourg%2CFrance&travelmode=driving&waypoints=Versailles%2CFrance%7CChartres%2CFrance%7CLe+Mans%2CFrance%7CCaen%2CFrance

For more examples reach out to official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#more-examples).

Answer (score 0):

This would be the place to check the guide
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Introduction

I'm not sure how different data set you get it in different platforms. but make sure you are giving a proper transport type, alterneteRequire flag and Optimize flag.

I noticed some trouble in parsing the polyline present in the legs which is giving some discontinued polyline path. I'm not sure though its my logic or the data is wrong.